# the best way to export a community site

Tags: export

We need to remove the Sharepoint community site posts which are older than 2 years to free up some space. The old posts need to be exported into some other format (maybe Excel, CSV, html), so that they can check them later without too much effort.

What can be the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

P.S. I have tried export the "Discussions List" to excel and download all files from "Site Assets" (which store the attachment of forum posts). However I cannot see the relationship between posts and their attachment.